# UICollectionView cells only display after second call to reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm probably doing something incredibly stupid, but I can't figure out for the life of me what's going on...

What I'm trying to do is quite simple. I have a `UICollectionView` dependent on data I'm loading from the server. After I get and set the data from the server, I call `reloadData()` on the collection view. When I do so, `numberOfItemsInSection` is called with the correct count, but `cellForItemAt` never gets called unless I call `reloadData()` for a second time (doesn't even need a delay).

Here's the general idea (although I realize it's likely related to some race conditional elsewhere, but maybe this will be enough to start the conversation):

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var data = [DataModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        getData()
    }

    func getData() {
        someAsyncMethodToGetData() { (data) in
            // Using CloudKit so I think this is necessary, but tried it with and without
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = data
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                // This is the only way to get cells to render and for cellForItemAt to be called after data is loaded
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    // Gets called initially AND after reloadData is called in the data completion closure. First time is 0, next time is number of DataModel objects
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    // Only gets called initially (unless I call reloadData() twice)
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = feedCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        // Configure the cell with data...

        return cell
    }
}
```

So here are some things I've already tried:

- Made double sure `reloadData()` is being called on the main thread (added a symbolic breakpoint and called `Thread.isMainThread` to verify)
- Moved `reloadData()` into a button action to eliminate the possibility of any thread issues - still had to click the button twice to get cells to show up
- Put the updates in `performBatchUpdates` based on some other SO solutions I came across
- Added `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` (not sure why this would be necessary in this case, but I did try it out of desperation.

Any suggestions?

## Update 1

Ok, think I found the issue, but I'd like to understand the best way to solve. It appears by calling `reloadData`, the collection view will only reload cells already visible. I hacked the code above a bit to return 1 cell before `getData()` is called. When `getData()` then calls `reloadData()` that 1 cell gets updated (but if there are 10 items in the data array, it will still only [re]display the 1 cell). I suppose this makes sense, as `reloadData()` only reloads visible cells, but this has to be a common issue when the length of the array changes and there is still room on the screen to display. Also, why does calling `reloadData()` twice solve the issue and display cells that were never visible?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/derrickshowers/b98c3a7b092f7dc70decf2cf042f2407) is an even simpler version of the code I have above, removing the whole "get data from a server" idea and replacing with a simple delay.

Comment: Just because code is executing on the main *thread*, it doesn't mean your code is executing on the main *queue*. Use a `Dispatch.main.async {}` to be sure. Where do you call `getData`?

Comment: I see. I am calling `Dispatch.main.async {}` in my data layer before calling the completion closure, but I also put it in the closure just to be sure. I call `getData` in `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing is UICollectionViewFlowLayout isn't invalidated correctly after number of items changed. So `collectionView.contentSize` is still old. You need to do something like

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

This will tell layout to recalculate for new data source.

Comment: That works! I'm really surprised that was so hard and there isn't more who have run into this. Seems like a common pattern. Oh well, hopefully this helps people in the future so they don't spend hours banging their head on the wall like me. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hello! I've encountered the same problem, but even after adding invalidateLayout() still happens the same thing. I have the same code in my class as above.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure if the delegate and the dataSource is correctly add to collectionView.

Second make sure if the data is fill whit breakpoint or a simple print

Third add this:

```
    DispatchQueque.main.async{
     self.collection.reloadData()
     self.collection.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```